# Windows 8 registry watcher

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry

Does anyone know of a reputable registry watcher program that alerts the user every time the registry is about to get modified?

I found a [list of 8 Tools to Track Registry and File Changes](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/tracking-registry-and-files-changes-when-installing-software-in-windows/), but I am not sure which one would be the best for Windows 8?

Comment: Any program that worked on Windows 7 is fine.  We don't do product recommendations here at Superuser.  I wouldn't use any of them to be honest they all seem unpolished

Answer (score 1):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

This utility has regmon built-in to it.  Watch out it catches everything and has 100,000 entries in a couple minutes easy.